# Do you use OpenEXR file format during making your video production? In the field of VFX

Tags: video, editing, file-formats, visual-effects

Do you use OpenEXR file format during making your video production? In the field of VFX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenEXR is mostly used for VFX.  It's a good format to get 3D renders into and out of compositing software because it can use 32 bits of precision, and store "deep pixel" information, such as vertex normals, ambient occlusion, z-depth, global illumination, etc.  The type of information is actually arbitrary; you could store temperature data on a per-pixel basis, if you wanted.  The files tend to be larger than most other formats, so if you don't have a good reason to use it, you shouldn't use it.

Comment: @Konskoo - if you have a question about colour depth, please don't ask it in a comment - that is not what these are for. Please post a well formed new question following the guidance in [about] and [ask]